# Add description tooltip directly to selected hat

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, winter-bash-2012

Is it possible to add the hat description tooltip directly to the hat element overlaying the gravatar? An illustration of what I mean *(with apologies to hims056)*:

[image]

I ask because I often spot someone wearing a hat I haven't seen before, which means I have to:

1. Go to their profile (if I'm not already there)
2. Open the hats popup
3. Scan through the list to find the selected hat (there is no highlight to indicate which one is selected) and hover it

Comment: Thanks for posting my photo... :)

Comment: @hims056 I hope you don't mind, yours was the hat I was trying to identify just now.

Comment: Three days left for hats, I really see no point in trivial feature requests...

Comment: @Manishearth It isn't like this is the only year we get Winter Bash you know. I am just suggesting an improvement to the UI.

Comment: While making sense, it'll all be over in three days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place this would make sense is on their profile page. Anywhere else their Gravatar is displayed is user-card-eligible.That means, for users which have the privilege for an expanded user-card, **hovering will expand the user-card**, so the tooltip would be useless since the hat does not get placed on the Gravatar in the user-card.

Since it would only be useful on their profile page, it doesn't seem like a very viable feature. You're already on their profile, and it's not really that difficult to click a link and scan. It's not like there are hundreds of hats.